# Parameters passed to a block

Tags: ruby, rest-client

The documentation for the [rest_client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) has the following example:

```
RestClient.get('http://my-rest-service.com/resource'){ |response, request, result, &block|
  case response.code
  when 200
    p "It worked !"
    response
  when 423
    raise SomeCustomExceptionIfYouWant
  else
    response.return!(request, result, &block)
  end
}
```

How do you know what attributes are available on each block variable above? What attributes do `response`, `request`, etc. have respectively? When I run `rest_client`:

```
response = RestClient.get('http://www.google.com')
```

lots of stuff are returned as `response`:

```
response.instance_variables # => [:@net_http_res, :@args, :@request, :@code]
response.net_http_res # => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
response.args # => {:method=>:get, :url=>"http://www.google.com", :headers=>{}}
response.code # => 200
```

What parts of `response` are available to the block? Does the order of the parameters matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, a method that accepts a block optionally will say something like this:

```
def f(...)
  if block_given?
    ...
    yield thing1, thing2...
    ...
    return foo
  else
    ...
    return bar
  end
end
```

Therefore, there does not need to be any correspondence between what is yielded to the block, and what is returned in case no block.

The way to know what the block receives is to look at the documentation for the method, or by consulting the source code.

Yes, order matters. The gem documentation specifically says `RestClient#get` gives you `response`, `request`, `result` and `block`; it also describes what those things are.

Answer (score 1):

From the `process_result` method in `restclient/request.rb`:

```
  if block_given?
    block.call(response, self, res, & block)
  else
```

This is where the block is called. Since `self` here is the `Request`, arguments given to the block are `response`, `request`, `result`, and the `block` itself in that particular order.

The block is called only if `block_given?` is true. Therefore, calling `RestClient.get` without a block, like you showed in the question, gives it a different behavior.

> What parts of response are available to the block?

The whole `Response` object is given to the block as the first parameter.

> Does the order of the parameters matter?

Yes, the order of the parameters definitely matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the particular gem you have, but in general, check the class:

```
p response.class
```

and then look for the documentation on that class, or directly look what methods it has by doing:

```
p response.methods
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response = RestClient.get('http://www.google.com')
```

when you fire this, you can have something like **response.methods** for the entire list available. This is pretty big so refer documentation/github page for commonly used methods. The response variable with all the methods are available to be used and passed directly.

Yes, the order of parameters matter in this.